# Azure App service shows crashes in diagnostics, but no metrics / alerting options

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring

We are moving on-prem hosting of ASP.Net framework 4.8 Web API from on-prem hosting to azure as app service. The plan is P2V3, should be enough for the testing. During testing the app service for load, we see there are application crashes taking place.

These are some 1-3 times a day. The event log, application logs do not have any records about the crash, but the Diagnose and solve problems -> Availability and performance -> application crashes shows these crashes taking place.

There are a few users' workflows broken, so we know this has affected the functionality.

Screenshot below:

[image: Application Crashes]

We want to monitor these crashes, but even the metrics for the app service (closest one is http server errors) show no blips. Nothing in activity logs either.

Can anyone suggest if this crash information can be monitored through metrics / any other source where alerts can be set up?

On a side note, we currently suspect snapshot debugger or some similar AI feature affecting this like here - https://www.koskila.net/how-to-fix-weird-production-breakpoints-errors-in-an-azure-app-service/ because we see no application errors and the snapshot debugger failures are present.

Comment: I’m looking for the same thing. Did you ever work it out? It seems bizarre that the platform can and does record this information but there’s no way to alert or monitor it continuously.

Answer (score -1):

The blog post talked about removing Application Insights from your app code. It's certainly a viable option. If you go that route, you can enable Application Insights on your app service and monitor that way. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources#application-data on different ways you can send Application Insight data into Azure Monitor

Comment: My primary need is to be able to get the app crash metrics for e.g. to add to dashboard or set alerts up